# Solr pagination tuning setting

Tags: solr, performance

We have our application designed with Solr, our users use lot of pages to go through. Sometime the next page browsing is slow..

In Oracle we have lot of parametrs to adjust to get better performance, like that Solr has any.

I read http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors no clues in this page. thx for help.

Is there a setting in Solr that can be tuned to increase performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you are still using default cache setting that comes out of the box. Check your current config for its setting. This is what you could try ,

**Typical default setting from solrconfig.xml**

```xml
<!-- An optimization for use with the queryResultCache.  When a search
     is requested, a superset of the requested number of document ids
     are collected.  For example, if a search for a particular query
     requests matching documents 10 through 19, and queryWindowSize is 50,
     then documents 0 through 49 will be collected and cached.  Any further
     requests in that range can be satisfied via the cache.  -->
<queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
<!-- Maximum number of documents to cache for any entry in the queryResultCache. -->
<queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
```

the above two parameters affect pagination, for instance if you app displays 25 results/page & your users are browsing 5 pages typically, set both `queryResultWindowSize`, `queryResultMaxDocsCached` to be 125. This will cache the results that a typical user behavior would require.

**Note:** These will have a impact on your memory, the degree of impact depends on your document size & other settings.